# Python2 error: --agents option requires an argument

Tags: python, python-2.x

Мне надо вывести список user-agent. Я должен вписать `%prog --agents` **БЕЗ АРГУМЕНТОВ!** Но мне все равно пишет что нужны аргументы. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Вот сам код.]

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Не используйте картинки для кода и вывода в консоли. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и добавьте необходимую информацию в виде текста. Нажмите [edit]

Comment: Извините, я решил данную проблему методом добавления action='store_true'

Comment: другим людям с похожей проблемой сложнее ваш вопрос будет найти если в нём даже `argparse` слово не употребляется. Связанный вопрос: [argparse module How to add option without any argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5262702/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Методом добавления action='store_true'.